# Bluetooth stereo using diferent devices

Tags: windows-10, linux-mint, bluetooth, speakers, stereo

I have two different Bluetooth speakers. Each one is mono.
I have my computer connected to both speakers at the same time but the sound is always mono in each one.

Can I use linux app or windows .exe to send a left channel to one speaker and the right channel to another, making it stereo?